# JQuery ajax fails to post with data params

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to using JQuery Ajax post a simple contact form using PHP as the handler.:

**Index.html**

```
<form  name="signup-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="signup-form">
   <input class="signup-input" type="email" name="email_address" value="" placeholder="enter your email..." title="Please enter a valid email address." required>
   <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

The corresponding JavaScript serializes the input from the browser correctly but I keep getting:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)`

**JS - site.json**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".signup-form").submit(function(e){

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "server.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          $(".the-return").html(
            "Email: " + data["email_address"]
          );

          alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);

        }
      });
    return false;
  });
});
```

**EDITED PHP - server.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function(); break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){

  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you do not output JSON at all (check your response in Inspector).

Comment: I know notice that its returning type 'XHR' even though i `json_encode` the POSTED output.

Comment: `dataType` is **The type of data that you're expecting back from the server**. I think you should also put JSON header: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and focus on PHP, your javascript is fine.

Comment: The problem is not with your jQuery, but most likely from the response sent by the PHP code.

Comment: Also, checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is not 100% reliable. Since you already check for `$_POST["action"]` you can add AJAX flag (as GET or POST).

Comment: You have an extra space before `<?php`. That will cause `header()` to fail. Check the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what's being returned by the AJAX call.

Comment: Are you sure your PHP's filename is `server.php` and it's beside your other file? Can you put the names of the files with your code?

Comment: The network tab still returns 'XHR' as the return type even after setting the mime media type and json encoding the `$_POST` object

Comment: Just one last question, are you sure index.html and server.php are next to each other (in the same folder)? I'm taking your codes and running them but I'm not getting the same errors. The only way I get `unexpected end` is when I change the URL of the ajax to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: No the  `server.php` file is hosted somewhere else and I am passing an absolute path to the resource

Comment: @DaveChen I finally got it! I was sending the wrong data on the client side as I kept going back and forth. After copying your snippet and changing my JS code back it worked. I will accept your answer as it helped me the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it's not working.

Your `is_ajax()` checks this `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`, which won't be set if you're using CORS. So an easy fix is just to disable this check.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-Type: application/json");

//print_r($_SERVER);

if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
  $action = $_POST["action"];
  switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
    case "test": test_function(); break;
  }
}

function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){
  $return = $_POST;

  //$return["email_address"] = json_encode($return);
  echo json_encode($return);
  exit;
}
```

Also don't forget the access the JSON with `data['email_address']`, there's nothing at `data['json']`.

Comment: I already had that removed. Can you post your full php snippet you are running with

Comment: Here's the full snippet. Make sure that server.php is accessible and where you expect it to be. You can first edit server.php to echo "hello world" or something and visit the remote URL to see if it is indeed the correct file.

Comment: To reproduce how I am running, I basically created that file `server.php` in the htdocs location using xampp and I am pointing to it directly in the javascript file. The file is found otherwise I get a 404 error

Comment: Is it still not working? is it possible that your the server you're hosting with is preventing CORS? Try adding a `.htaccess` file including `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. Oh and are you testing this on your own computer? Have you port forwarded so that you can test it with your external IP?

Comment: Everything is local at the moment as I try to get this working. The server.php file is referenced from the htdocs running localhost

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but one thing that's apparent is your PHP code is returning a nested object.

```
{email_address: "{"email_address":"asdf@asdf.org","action":"test"}", action: "test"}
```

This is what your JSON looks like on the way back.  If you wanted to just spit the $_POST data back to your browser, you could simply do:

```
function test_function(){
  echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

And then modify your alert in your success method on the JS side:

```
alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json:\n" + JSON.stringify(data));
```

One other thing, it's a really good idea to set your content-type header in your php code, probably after you check for X-Requested-With, but before you spit out any data to the browser:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: In my use case here, could I then set the `header('Content-type: application/json');` right in my `test_function` before I spit the `$_POST` data back because I am still getting the same error?

Comment: As long as you've not echoed anything to the screen before calling test_function, then it shouldn't give you an error.  That being said, I'd guess that eventually you'll add other methods that do actual useful work, and all of them will want the content type header set so to me it would make more sense to do it after determining you've received an XHR request.  As others have pointed out, this isn't always present, but jQuery AJAX should always set it.